# How to create database in LMDB?

Tags: python, lmdb

I'm trying to use LMDB. After installing LMDB with pip, I tried following:

```
import lmdb
env = lmdb.open('test001', map_size=1000)
```

at this point I get the following error.

```
lmdb.InvalidParameterError: test001: Invalid argument
```

I do see a folder named test001 is created, with a file called lock.mdb in it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your example works on mine machine without errors

Comment: @AzatIbrakov That's good to know. I'll look into problems in packages/dependencies.

Comment: same problem. could you find the reason?

Comment: You can't create lmdb database in a shared folder, just like in the case of virtualbox shared folder.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was trying to create the LMDB in a shared folder in VM, as suggested in comments. Creating the DB in native mount solves the issue.